# i want to add partition on my old ubuntu which has no additional drive

Tags: partitioning

gParted is not working with the dragging and moving. no 'new partition' option is showing, how can i do additional partition? i am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

[image: 'new' button greyed out]
[image: resizing]

Comment: Are you running from the drive itself ? If so, you can't resize a partition from which Ubuntu is currently running - you'll need to use a live DVD / USB to do the resizing.

Comment: Did you try to type in a smaller size to shrink partition 1? (from screen shot 2)

Comment: yes, but it is not working.. @ubfan1

Answer (score 1):

On the first image, you can see a key next to your sda1 which means that you can not change the size of this partition. The reason for this is that you are running your system on this drive. When resizing the partition blocks may be moved which is dangerous on a running system.

**Solution**:
Download a live system of your choice like Ubuntu or Parted Magic and burn it on a CD or a USB stick. When running a live system you can change the size of the partition. After starting the live system also make sure that the partition you want to resize is not mounted. If it is you have to unmount it using parted itself or via terminal typing: `umount /dev/sda1` if the partition you want to change is on sda1.

Comment: if i unmount sd1, is there will remain my all data of the drive ?

Comment: Mounting a device makes the file system on the device accessible. When unmounted, you can not use the filesystem but the data remains on the harddrive. That being said unmounting a device does not affect your data. On the other hand resizing the partition may cause damages to the harddrive. Normally there is only a small chance for that to happen but in case that you have a second/external harddrive: do a backup before resizing.